# How to re-transform XSTL to XSLT with additional tags added

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to the XSLT 1.0, where i have the below XML which we are passing into XSLT to generate the PDF.

XML:

```
<Family>
     <Description>General psychiatry</Description>
</Family> 

<Family>
    <Description>Liaison Psychiatry</Description>
    <Parent>General psychiatry</Parent>
</Family>

 <Family>
    <Description>Old age psychiatry</Description>
</Family>

<Family>
    <Description>General psychiatry</Description>
</Family> 

<Family>
     <Description>Liaison</Description>
     <Parent>General psychiatry</Parent>
</Family>
```

Case 1:
The first-Family-tag holds the parent name(Description) and in the second-Family-tag will hold the child name(Decription) and the parent name(Parent).

Case 2:
Will have only first-Family-tag holds the parent name(Description) but there will no second-Family-tag.

Now i need to group the above based on the Parent- Child/Children's, i thought of using THE MUENCHIAN METHOD but this need all the Family-tag should have the same sub-tags under it and i can't change the XML format as well.

Any suggestion to overcome the above 2 cased and group based on the Family-tag is most appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You are not transforming XSLT to XSLT. You are using XSLT to transform XML to XML. Precision please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **XSLT 2.0** you can use for-each-group

```
<xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="//Family[count(*) = 1][Description]" group-by=".">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="Description"/>
                    <xsl:if test="//Family[Parent = current-group()[1]/Description]">
                        <SubFamily>
                            <xsl:for-each select="//Family[Parent = current-group()[1]/Description]">
                                <xsl:copy-of select="Description"/>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </SubFamily>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

See Transformation at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSTbfe

In **XSLT 1.0** using MUENCHIAN METHOD

```
<xsl:key name="parent" match="Family" use="Description"/>

        <xsl:key name="child" match="Family" use="Parent"/>

        <xsl:template match="root">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:for-each select="Family[not(Parent)][generate-id() = generate-id(key('parent', Description)[1])]">
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="Description"/>
                        <xsl:if test="//Family[Parent = current()/Description]">
                            <SubFamily>
                                <xsl:for-each select="//Family[Parent = current()/Description]">
                                    <xsl:copy-of select="Description"/>   
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </SubFamily>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>
```

See Transformation at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NSTbfe/1

Comment: Thanks Rupesh_Kr, its working 100%. Thanks a lot :)